# How to secure JWT token to avoid sharing it from one computer to another

Tags: ssl, jwt, websecurity

I am currently using JWT Token with 256 hashing algorithm which expires every 5 minutes, now my problem is how can I secure the token to prevent it from copying the token from (`Local Storage` or `Cookie`) to another computer.  Is there a way to prevent this kind of attack? Also take note that we use **SSL** as well in our site but still, we treat this as a security-flaw.  Is there a way to prevent the token from copying from one computer to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should not put your tokens or secret items in the localStorage as it brings a vulnerability from XSS (Cross site scripting). This is because localStorage is always accesible through javascript and a XSS could add a malicious script that sends a token to another server.

You should put your tokens on cookies with [http only flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies). This avoids them being accesible through javascript.

I would also recommend reading about [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) so the adequate protection is given to avoid CSRF (Cross site request forgery).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very helpful!